# Text not appearing on ios / android device but working fine on simulator

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I've been working on deploying a react-native project which has been working (and continues to work) fine on both ios and android simulator. I've recently deployed it to beta in the playstore and testflight and when we launch the app it appears that some placeholder & default text is missing :-(

I'm new to react-native development, so any advice is greatly appreciated. Could it be that i'm missing something when generating my app bundle? I'm using react-native: 0.55.4. Below is the code on my login page where the labels are missing & the inputs are not being passed to the subsequent page.

.
.
.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        isJobOwner: false,
        saveCredentials: false,
        isLoading: false
    };
}
```

.
.
.

```
onPressLogin() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUpChoice', {
        data: {
            username: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password
        }
    });
}
```

.
.
.

```
<Form style={styles.loginForm}>
                    <View style={styles.formInputs}>
                        <UnderlinedInput floating={true} label={'Email'} value={this.state.username}
                                         onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({username})}
                                         keyboardType={'email-address'} autoCapitalize={'none'}/>
                        <UnderlinedInput floating={true} label={'Password'} value={this.state.password}
                                         onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
                                         secureTextEntry={true}
                                         autoCapitalize={'none'}/>

                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.formButtons}>
                        <Button transparent
                                onPress={() => this.onPressForgotPassword()}
                                disabled={this.state.isLoading} style={styles.forgotButtonStyle}><Text
                            style={styles.forgotTextStyle}>Forgot
                            Password?</Text></Button>
                        <Button primary style={styles.loginButtonStyle} onPress={() => this.onPressLogin()}
                                disabled={this.state.isLoading}>
                            <Text style={styles.loginTextStyle}>Sign In</Text>
                        </Button>
                    </View>
```

.
.
.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
const data = state.data.loginReducer;
return {
    requesting: data.requesting,
    successful: data.successful,
    errors: data.errors,
    isJobOwner: data.isJobOwner
}
```

}

.
.
.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginScreen);
```

This is all working fine in on the simulators but on the devices its as if the the state is not being updated.

Edit: Including the source for the UnderlinedInput

```
import React from 'react';
import {Item, Input, Label} from 'native-base';
import colors from 'Colors';

const UnderlinedInput = ({defaultValue, label, value, onChangeText, secureTextEntry, keyboardType, autoCapitalize, floating, onEndEditing}) => {
return (
    <Item floatingLabel={floating} stackedLabel={!floating} style={styles.inputTextStyle}>
        <Label style={styles.labelStyle}>{label}</Label>
        <Input
            secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry || false}
            autoCorrect={false}
            autoCapitalize={autoCapitalize || 'words'}
            value={value}
            onChangeText={onChangeText}
            keyboardType={keyboardType || 'default'}
            defaultValue={defaultValue}
            onEndEditing={onEndEditing}
            style={styles.inputMainStyle}
        />
    </Item>
);
```

};

```
const styles = {
    inputTextStyle: {
        borderBottomColor: colors.lightGrey,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        color: colors.lightGrey,
        width: '80%',
        marginLeft: 'auto',
        marginRight: 'auto',
        paddingBottom: 10
    },
    inputMainStyle: {
        color: colors.lightGrey,
        fontSize: 14
    },
    labelStyle: {
        fontWeight: '700',
        letterSpacing: 1,
        paddingTop: 4,
        color: colors.lightGrey,
        fontSize: 14
    }
};
```

export default UnderlinedInput;

Answer (score 0):

from my point of view, it's because you are using a third party libraries UnderlinedInput, be sure that those components are not 100% reliable, they my not work on some devices, or for some cases. If you try for exemple to use a simple TextInput, Iam sure it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I think the UnderlinedInput is a component that used quite standard react-native controls editing original post to include. If it was this component specifically wouldn't it break in the simulator first?

Comment: Like i said, it may not work on some* devices, or fore some cases* . But
I just noticed something, for exemple in keyboardType , the value assigned is a string, so why are you adding the braquet {}, when the value is a String, you don't have to add those braquet {}, juste write for exemple, keyboardType = "email-adresse". So  try to remove them when u have a String